# What script is used for creating usbboot partition, and installing grub in mkusb

Tags: boot, grub2, usb, live-usb, usb-installation

### What script is used for creating partition 3, (usbboot), and installing grub in mkusb.

I am trying to answer a question in ASK concerning building a multiboot USB from scratch, but hit a wall with installing grub2 and the boot partition and grub folder.

Most of the answers I can find in Ask concerning installing grub refer to legacy grub not grub2.

I tried looking at the source code of mkusb but all I saw was a haze.

A link to the shellscript would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer

In mkusb I use the shellscript `dus-persistent` to create the persistent live system. It consists of several functions, and specifically the function `grub_n_iso` to create partitions and put things into them. (The name is inherited from an [old system](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2259682), where iso files were used.)

### Longer answer

If you have already [installed mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Quick_start_manual_and_mkusb_PPA), you can read the file `dus-persistent` with `less` or with your favourite text editor.

```
less /usr/sbin/dus-persistent
```

If you have not installed it yet, you can read it via the following link,

[phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/mkusb/dus-persistent](https://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/mkusb/dus-persistent)

### Detailed answer

But I think you want more detailed information, that shows the details, where the third partition `usbboot` is created and filled with content (`grub`).

#### 1. From the function `grub_n_iso`

```
echo "item 30"
echo "30
# make partitions: preparing $part" >> "$tailfile"

if $grubimg
then
 /bin/echo -e "$inversvid using grub.img: keeping file system of $part: $resetvid "
else
 echo "preparing $part  ------------------------------------------------"
 dd if=/dev/zero of="$part" bs=1024 count=1024 2>&1
 sync
 umount  "$part" 2>&1
 sync
 sleep 1
 mkfs.vfat -v -F 32 "$part"
 echo " "
 sync
 sleep 0.5
fi
```

In several versions of Ubuntu when installed, it is difficult to create grub for the 'other' boot mode, particularly to create grub for BIOS mode when booted in UEFI mode. For this reason there is an image `grub.img`, prepared like described below, that can be used.

When suitable, the partition is created with `mkfs.vfat`, and it will be labeled `usbboot`.

```
label="usbboot"
dosfslabel "$part" "$label"
```

#### 2. From the function `grub_n_iso`

```
echo "item 70"
echo "70
# installing bootloaders" >> "$tailfile"

if [ "$distr" == "opensuse" ]
then
 grub_inst=grub2-install
else
 grub_inst=grub-install
fi

if $grubimg
then
 /bin/echo -ne "$inversvid UEFI Bootloader: $resetvid "
 $grub_inst --force --removable --no-floppy --boot-directory="$targ1"/boot \
 --efi-directory="$targ1"/EFI/BOOT "$2" 2>&1
fi

if $biosbl
then
 /bin/echo -ne "$inversvid UEFI Bootloader: $resetvid "
 $grub_inst --force --removable --no-floppy --boot-directory="$targ1"/boot \
 --efi-directory="$targ1"/EFI/BOOT "$2" 2>&1
elif ! test -f "$looper"/boot/grub/grub.cfg
then
 if test -f "$mkusb_sdir"/usb-pack_efi.tar.gz
 then
  if ! $upefi
  then
   echo "$inversvid Select 'upefi' to use 'usb-pack-efi' $resetvid"
  fi
 else
  /bin/echo -e "$inversvid No 'grub.cfg' for the UEFI Bootloader found in the iso file $resetvid
${version% *} needs the package 'usb-pack-efi' with the file
'usb-pack_efi.tar.gz' to make a persistent live system with
this iso file boot in UEFI mode."
  if test -f /usr/bin/apt-get
  then
   echo "You can use the following command lines in a terminal window.

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install usb-pack-efi"
  else
   echo "
Use search string 'ubuntu dus-plus' for the tarball 'dus-plus' which contains
'usb-pack-efi'. Be prepared to tweak the system manually afterwards. It may be
difficult to create a persistent live system in your linux distro."
   echo "$separator"
  fi
 fi
 if $grubimg
 then
  /bin/echo -e "$inversvid BIOS Bootloader via 'grub.img': $resetvid "
 else
  /bin/echo -ne "$inversvid BIOS Bootloader: $resetvid "
  $grub_inst --force --removable --no-floppy --boot-directory="$targ1"/boot "$2" 2>&1
 fi
fi
```

- The command `grub-install` is used (in Ubuntu and Debian). It uses the option `--efi-directory` for the UEFI bootloader.
- If the setting 'upefi' (usb-pack-efi) is selected or necessary, it will be extracted.
- The command `grub-install` is used again. For obvious reasons it does *not* use the option `--efi-directory` for the BIOS bootloader.

#### 3. From the function `grub_n_iso`

```
echo "item 80"
echo "80
# copying files ..." >> "$tailfile"

error=""

# start copy/extract boot files (not upefi) ----------------------------

if ! $upefi && test -f "$looper"/boot/grub/grub.cfg
then

# copy the boot files from the iso file

/bin/echo -e "$inversvid 64-bit bootloader: copy the boot files from the iso file $resetvid"
echo "looper=$looper"
echo "targ1=$targ1"

rsync -Ha --exclude=filesystem.squashfs "$looper/" "$targ1"
symlink_error_comment="rsync:$inversvid  don't worry, $resetvid symlink errors are *expected*
because of the target file system."
/bin/echo -e "$symlink_error_comment"
#if [ "$disk_name_type" == "debian" ] && [ "$release" == "stretch" ]
#then
# mount -o loop "$looper"/boot/grub/efi.img "$loopefi"
# rsync -Ha "$loopefi/efi" "$targ1"
# umount  "$loopefi"
# ls -l "$targ1"|grep ^d    ###
# find "$targ1/efi"         ###
# read -p "after rsync efi" ###
#fi

is_file "$targ1"/boot/grub/grub.cfg
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
 echo "'$targ1/boot/grub/grub.cfg': file not found"
 echo "This way to use ${version% *} needs 'grub.cfg' from the source iso file,"
 echo "and it is available in Debian and Ubuntu family *amd64* iso files"
 clear_grn "$pid" "$looper" "$targ1" "$tailfile" "$usbdata"
 exit
fi

# tweak 1 grub.cfg

sed "$targ1"/boot/grub/grub.cfg \
-e '/menuentry/a \ set root=(hd0,4)' \
-e '/linux/s#/#($root)/#' \
-e '/initrd/s#/#($root)/#' \
> "$targ1"/boot/grub/grub.cfg0
sync
menu_entry_1 "$targ1"/boot/grub/grub.cfg0 "$targ1"/boot/grub/grub.cfg
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
 error="$error - menu_entry_1: tweaking grub.cfg"
fi
rm "$targ1"/boot/grub/grub.cfg0

else  # ... copy/extract boot files (upefi) ----------------------------

# extract files originally from Andre's zip-file (except grub.cfg grub4dos/ ini/)

if $grubimg
then
 /bin/echo -e "$inversvid Bootloaders via 'grub.img', skipping 'usb-pack_efi': $resetvid "
 rm "$targ1"/boot/grub/grub.cfg
else
 if test -f "$mkusb_sdir"/usb-pack_efi.tar.gz
 then
  echo "using usb-pack_efi.tar.gz"
  tar -xvzf "$mkusb_sdir"/usb-pack_efi.tar.gz --directory "$targ1"
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]
  then
   error="- tar: extracting usb-pack_efi"
  fi
 fi
fi

# tweak 2 grub.cfg

if ! test -f "$targ1"/boot/grub/grub.cfg
then
 < "$mkusb_sdir"/grub.cfg sed '2'q > "$targ1"/boot/grub/grub.cfg  # copy two first lines
 if [ $? -ne 0 ]
 then
  error="$error - sed: copying start of grub.cfg"
 fi
fi
sync
sleep 0.5
cat "$targ1"/boot/grub/grub.cfg

# append the rest of the file (after two first lines)

menu_name

< "$mkusb_sdir"/grub.cfg sed -e '1,2'd \
-e '/menuentry "ubuntu/a \ set root=(hd0,4)' \
-e '/menuentry "memtest/a \  set root=(hd0,3)' \
-e '/loopback/d' -e 's#iso-scan/filename=/ubuntu.iso ##' \
-e 's/loop/$root/' \
-e "s%ubuntu.iso%$menuname%g" \
-e "s/vmlinuz/$vmlinuz/" \
-e "s/casper/$persist/g" \
-e "s/initrd.lz/$initrd/" \
-e '/menuentry/s/"./\U&/' \
>> "$targ1"/boot/grub/grub.cfg

#read -p "at 'append the rest of the file (after two first lines)'
#disk_name_type=$disk_name_type"

if [ "$disk_name_type" == "debian" ] \
|| [ "$disk_name_type" == "torios-debian" ] \
|| [ "$disk_name_type" == "9w-debian-wheezy" ]
then
 sed -i 's/persistent --/persistence --/' "$targ1"/boot/grub/grub.cfg
fi

if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
 error="$error - sed: appending grub.cfg"
fi

fi  # end copy/extract boot files --------------------------------------
```

I do not add more detailed explanations now. Please specify exactly what needs to be explained, if you want more details.

Comment: Thanks I will try to work through this. Personally I am generally happy to use a mkusb install as a foundation, But I got an urge to try this from "scratch".

Comment: @C.S.Cameron, A convenient alternative might be to make a template for your systems: to use or even extend the image `grub.img` so that you can use such an image instead of running the whole mkusb and then overwrite most of what it has created.